# Java - output from line read in reverse

Tags: java, line, reverse

The following routine outputs moves from a chess engine to a JTextArea

```
public void getEngineOutputOriginal(Process engine) 
{
    try {           
        BufferedReader reader =
          new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (engine.getInputStream ()), 1);
        String lineRead = null;
        // send engine analysis to print method
        while ((lineRead = reader.readLine ()) != null)
           Application.showEngineAnalysis (lineRead);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Sample output would be

```
           12     3.49  39/40?  2. b4      (656Knps)             
           12     3.49  40/40?  2. Nd5     (656Knps)             
           12->   3.51   0.04   2. Bxf4 Be6 3. Be3 Qa5 4. Nd5 Qxd2
           13     3.51   1/40?  2. Bxf4    (655Knps)
```

Is it possible to reverse the process so that the last line read always appears at the top instead of the bottom, like so:

```
           13     3.51   1/40?  2. Bxf4    (655Knps)   
           12->   3.51   0.04   2. Bxf4 Be6 3. Be3 Qa5 4. Nd5 Qxd2
           12     3.49  40/40?  2. Nd5     (656Knps)             
           12     3.49  39/40?  2. b4      (656Knps)
```

I have researched Google and I couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 2):

Sure!  One option would just be to buffer the lines into an `ArrayList`, then display them all in reverse order at the end:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

/* Add all lines from the file to the buffer. */
while((lineRead = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    lines.add(lineRead);
}

/* Replay them in reverse order. */
for (int i = lines.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     Application.showEngineAnalysis(lines.get(i));
}
```

Conceptually speaking, you can think of this as making a stack, pushing all the lines onto the stack, then popping them off one at a time.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That sounds great - thanks for the quick response.  I'll give it a go.

Comment: Code works great, however I only see the reverse analysis when I stop the routine running, i.e. it doesn't refresh as it runs, etc.  Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: @user1432365- Oh, I see what you're saying.  I thought that the process had completed when you were running the above program.  You will probably need to look at your logger for details about how to reverse the output.

Comment: When you say logger do you mean my output method, which is:   public static void showEngineAnalysis (String message) {

  if (message.length() > 0)
   message += "\n";
  Application.obj.engineOutput.append(message);

 }

Comment: @user1432365- Yes, you'd need to update that method to display at the top rather than at the bottom.  I don't know what Application.obj.engineOutput is, but you should just prepend the message rather than appending it.

Comment: Effectively then, I could use a variant of your code and stack the line reads and reverse their order as they are received by the logger?  Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the prepend tip - I have never heard of that function before but it seems to offer better performance